# Indesign: Error encountered while reading JPEG

Tags: adobe-indesign, error

Does anybody know how to fix this error? It doesn't say anywhere what image gives the error. Preflight doesn't show either. Its hard to figure out which image it is when i have used several jpeg files in my layout.

> Export: ... Failed. See Alert.
>
> Error encountered while reading JPEG image. Image may be damaged or incompatible. Resave the image with different settings and try again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The alert box does not say what the damaged JPG is? How many JPGs are placed in your INDD? If not many, you can take a few minutes and with the "process of elimination" start deleting 1 JPG at a time and try re-exporting as PDF. If there are a lot of JPGs in the INDD, still do the "process of elimination" BUT try deleting entire pages. There's no telling what's broken about the JPG without Photoshop, but you can at least find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can try *before* exporting:

- Check your `Links` panel and see if there are any missing/corrupt images.
- Do a `Preflight` and see if that reports any errors.
- Check if there's any leftover images outside your artboards.
- Check if any of the images are still open/unsaved in other apps (Photoshop etc) or locked in a syncing app like Dropbox or Google Drive, or on an external drive?

Answer (score 1):

Save the document as an idml - re-open and see errors. You can then replace the damaged file - Indesign will place the damaged JPEG as an EPS.